# MySQL select the average timedifference between two timestamp columns for a particular id in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time, average

I have a table `visits` that looks like this:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| vis_id       | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| unit         | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| time_in      | timestamp   | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| time_out     | timestamp   | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| in_username  | varchar(16) | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| out_username | varchar(16) | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I use this to keep track of visitors coming in and out of my building.

What I'd like is to be able to see the "average length of visit" in hours by a particular visitor (defined by `vis_id`). If the average visit length is less than an hour it should round up to 1.

Here's an example of what I'd like for output:

```
+--------+------+----------+
| vis_id | unit | avg_time |
+--------+------+----------+
|    156 |  216 | 5        |
|   1230 |  103 | 2        |
|    533 |  112 | 1        |  
|    802 |  201 | 3        |
|   1445 |  431 | 4        |
+--------+------+----------+
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AVG()` grouping function. As far as I see, you'll need two grouping fields, like below:

```
SELECT 
  vis_id,
  unit,
  ROUND(AVG((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_out)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_in))/3600)) AS avg_time
FROM
  visits
GROUP BY
  vis_id,
  unit
```

Note, that I'm using [`ROUND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) since you've not defined rules for dealing with non-integer values. `ROUND()` will use algebraic rule, but may be you'll want to drop non-integer part. Then look to [`FLOOR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) - or, instead, add integer part (i.e. round to greatest) - then look to [`CEIL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil)

Comment: That works well, but `ROUND` brings it down to `0` instead of up to `1`... can I change it to _always_ round up no matter what?

Comment: Thanks, will accept as the answer when the timer runs down!